# How to hide dynamically created controls in scrollable panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem, because in my code I am dynamically creating new buttons, and after that, the window looks in that way:

[image]

This is code that I used for that:

```
private void DrawButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
    {

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(15 + 40 * i, 10);
        button.Size = new Size(35, 30);
        button.Parent = panel4;

        button.Tag = i;
        Controls.Add(button);

        button.BringToFront();

    }
}
```

I want to have scrollable panel, like there, where I created buttons manually:

[image]

What I must do to have this effect with programically created elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AutoScroll` property. For `Panel`:

```
panel4.AutoScroll = true;
```

But you should also set this property:

```
button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
```

And also add the button to your `Panel`:

```
panel4.Controls.Add(button);
```

So this should be what you want:

```
 private void DrawButtons()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
     {
         ...
         button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
         ...
         panel4.Controls.Add(button);//Add this also
         ...
     }
     panel4.AutoScroll = true;
 }
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @Michael See my updated answer. You should set the `Anchor` property also. `button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;`